# ti.main.js file not found in xcode. But it works fine in appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator

We have built a titanium application which works fine in the Appcelerator, but when we open and built the same in the Xcode, it is throwing an error like could not find the file ti.main.js.
Below are the details of the error, which we are getting in the emulator.

---

```
Could not find the file ti.main.js

4   POC  0x000000010f693d8c -[KrollInvocation invoke:] + 124
5   POC  0x000000010f695d97 -[KrollContext 
invokeOnThread:method:withObject:callback:selector:] + 199
6   POC  0x000000010f68e254 -[KrollBridge evalFile:callback:selector:] + 116
7   POC  0x000000010f68f1f7 -[KrollBridge didStartNewContext:] + 2935
8   POC  0x000000010f6969cd -[KrollContext main] + 2413
9   Foundation 0x0000000112e77732 __NSThread__start__ + 1221
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001191f4661 _pthread_body + 340
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001191f450d _pthread_body + 0
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001191f3bf9 thread_start + 13
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any reason why you want to re-open it in xcode? Did you use Liveview (if so, run a build without it)?

Comment: Wanted to generate an ios installation file(.ipa) in xcode. I am able to generate .ipa file but when we install it into physical device with the help of xcode, it throwes error. Same which is attached above.

Comment: My problem got resolved.

Comment: would be helpful for other people if you add the solution. E.g. create the IPA with CLI or include the framework in Xcode,..

Comment: @sandeepsingh I get the same error in xcode, It would be great if you post the solution about how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I have same issue, any solutions?

Comment: Please, how did you solve the problem? I am facing a similar issue. If you could provide the solution, it would be great! @sandeepsingh